# How to search multiple data & model type of data in autocomplete textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, autocompletetextview

```
 Expanded(
                    flex:1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12,top: 16,bottom: 12),
                      child: AutoCompleteTextField(
                        key: key,
                        controller: controller.recommendedTxt.value,
                        suggestions: controller.specialityList,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: fontMulishSemiBold,
                            fontSize: 15.sp,
                            color: black_1e1f20),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          isDense: true,
                          hintText: str_search,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: silver_9393aa,
                              fontSize: 15.sp,
                              fontFamily: fontMulishSemiBold
                          ),
                          prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
                            maxHeight: 24,
                            maxWidth: 24,
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5,right: 5),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              icon_search,
                              color: silver_9393aa,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        itemFilter: (item, query) {
                          return item
                              .toString()
                              .toLowerCase()
                              .startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
                        },
                        itemSorter: (a, b) {
                          return a.toString().compareTo(b.toString());
                        },
                        itemSubmitted: (item) {
                          controller.recommendedTxt.value.text = item.toString();
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                          return Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w,right: 16.w,top: 20.h),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: light_green_f8fbff,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  item.toStringView(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.sp,
                                      fontFamily: fontMulishSemiBold,
                                      color: black_1e1f20),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 19.5.h,),
                                const Line()

                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),


                    ),
                  ),
```

Above, Is my AutoCompleteTextField in which, suggestions has model type of list. When I search anything it shows an object error.

```
  var recommendedTxt = new TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<SpecialityDatum>> key = GlobalKey();
```

Below is my model,

```
 class SpecialityDatum {
  SpecialityDatum({
     this.id,
     this.speciality,
     this.status,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.deletedAt,
  });

  int? id;
  String? speciality;
  int? status;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  dynamic deletedAt;

  factory SpecialityDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SpecialityDatum(
    id: json["id"]??0,
    speciality: json["speciality"]??"",
    status: json["status"]??"",
    createdAt: json["created_at"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]) : null,
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]) : null,
    deletedAt: json["deleted_at"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "speciality": speciality,
    "status": status,
    "created_at": createdAt,
    "updated_at": updatedAt,
    "deleted_at": deletedAt,
  };

  String toStringView(){ // what ever you name it
    return '$id $speciality'; // if you want to show id and speciality as string
  }

}
```

Here is my list,   `var specialityList = <SpecialityDatum>[].obs;`

In first image has error,

[image]

Result I want,

[image]

In second image it shows list of medicines name. I want speciality name from model list instead of that. How to set model list there. I tried multiple solution but it doesn't work. How it will work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your builder , you showing object, thats why its display instance.

- option 1 :

```
itemBuilder: (context, item) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w,right: 16.w,top: 20.h),
    ....
     children: [
        Text(
          item.speciality.toString(),  // if you wan to show speciality
```

- option 2:

add this to your model

```
.....

String toStringView(){ // what ever you name it
 return '$id $speciality' // if you want to show id and speciality as string
}
```

then call it on your builder

```
itemBuilder: (context, item) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w,right: 16.w,top: 20.h),
    ....
     children: [
        Text(
          item.toStringView(),
```

Comment: I tried option2. but in itembuilder text it shows an error The method 'toStringView' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Comment: basically its only simple method to return `String` , I just tried ,and no error occurs. can you update your current code

Comment: I updated my code. Plz go through that. I dont know where i'm doing mistake

Comment: how about option 1, is it work or same issue?

Comment: what package did you use, it hard to debug without know exact third party package

Comment: Option one has item as a string. so, doesn't have speciality sttring.

Comment: autocomplete_textfield: ^2.0.1

Comment: autocomplete_textfield plugin I have used

Comment: i think `item` should not a `String`. since you declare global  key as Object Model.

and you cant compare object with a String. not only in `itemBuilder`,  also in `itemFilter`, `itemSorter`  and `itemSubmited`

Comment: for debuging purpose, remove `itemFilter` , `itemSorter`, and `itemSubmitter` 

then try if its work or not. and also you can add model to : `child: AutoCompleteTextField<SpecialityDatum>(`